# How to ignore type column for model in link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have `Pet`s and `Cat`s. Cats are stored in the `pets` table with the value 'Cat' in the `type` column.

Let's say I create a link like this:

```
link_to 'My Pet', Pet.find(1)
```

This will generate a link using the `pet_path` as expected.

But then let's say I create a link like this:

```
link_to 'My Pet', Cat.find(1)
```

This will generate a link using the 'cat_path', which is smart, but not what I want because I only have/need a PetController.

Clearly, I can just use `pet_path(Cat.find(1))` in the link_to, but I'm wondering if there is a more robust solution. What if I have Dogs, Birds, etc.? I don't want to have to remember to explicitly use `pet_path` every time.

How can I make sure that the second link will create a link with the `pet_path` moving forward? Is there a setting on the Cat model or the Pet model or something I can put in routes.rb to **ensure** this?

-edit-

There's some confusion over what I'm trying to achieve. I simply want to know how to make sure that a call to link_to with a Cat object will resolve to a pet_path instead of a cat_path. I'm not looking for a way to change how my table is set up. In an ideal situation, I wouldn't have to create a bunch of controllers for the different pet types either. I'd like to know whether there is a simple, elegant way to tell Rails to use the parent class for a model when determining the url helper.

Comment: How is `Cat` different from `Pet`? If you expect to have more pets in the future, why not also make a `Cat` class?

Comment: Sounds like you have two models using the same DB table? If your problem is just with the routing helpers, you can simply define `cat_path` and other cat-related helpers, and route them to actions in the PetController (if you have REST actions you can just do `resources :cats, controller: 'pet'`). Or have a base PetController and then define CatController, DogController, etc. as derived classes, to keep your code DRY. Much depends on your personal preference and what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: What I want to achieve is making sure that a call to link_to with a Cat object will go through the pet_path. I don't Rails to try to be smart about it and generate a cat_path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create custom routes either manually

```
get    'cats/:id' => 'pets#show'
put    'cats/:id' => 'pets#update'
delete 'cats/:id' => 'pets#destroy'
# etc etc
...
```

or using resources

```
resources :cats, controller: 'pet'
```

Slightly outside the scope of your question, but the create action could test the url `request.original_url` and know what kind of pet to create based on what path was called with the `POST` command.